# Setting to prevent R from updating libraries installed using apt

Tags: r, libraries

Could someone enlighten me as to how to set up one's .Rprofile or .Renviron files to prevent the system from upgrading libraries installed via Ubuntu's apt package managing system? It seems like on should be able to set the option for update.packages() to only look at, say, '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library'.

Comment: I doubt that you could affect apt's behaviour from R's configuration settings. Your best bet would be to restrict apt from updating the packages directly.

Comment: @heds1 I think you've got it backwards.  I'm trying to get R to ignore the libraries installed via `apt`

Comment: This [post](https://coolbutuseless.github.io/2018/04/11/changing-the-default-arguments-to-a-function/) seems useful.  I will look into using the default library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This partially works in that I can assign a single value to the default value of `lib.loc`.

```
library(default) ## Load library
default(update.packages) <- list(lib.loc="/usr/local/lib/R/site-library")
> default(update.packages)
* - lib.loc = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"
  - repos = getOption("repos")
  - contriburl = contrib.url(repos, type)
  - method = [none]
  - instlib = NULL
  - ask = TRUE
  - available = NULL
  - oldPkgs = NULL
  - ... = [none]
  - checkBuilt = FALSE
  - type = getOption("pkgType")
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work when using more than one value. For example, here the default values are all wonky.

```
default(update.packages) <- list(lib.loc=c("/usr/local/lib/R/site-library", "/home/<user>/R/lib/4.1")
> default(update.packages)
* - c("lib.loc = \"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library\"", "lib.loc = \"/home/<user>/R/lib\"")
  - repos = getOption("repos")
  - contriburl = contrib.url(repos, type)
  - method = [none]
  - instlib = NULL
  - ask = TRUE
  - available = NULL
  - oldPkgs = NULL
  - ... = [none]
  - checkBuilt = FALSE
  - type = getOption("pkgType")
```